# Clear the attributed text of textfield from the IB clear button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am not able to clear the attributed text of `UITextField` when the Interface Button `clear` button is triggered.

I have tried `_textfield.attributedText = nil;` but it doesn't work. What happens next is that the UI freezes and I am not able to interact with the UI anymore.

Moreover, the `attributedText` is not removed from the UI.

**Note:**
I can't use `text` property of textfield because I have an `icon` and a `string` inside my `attributedText`. Hence, I must use this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Ronak

Comment: Did you try to set _textfield.attributedText in the main thread?

Comment: can you add video or gif for this?

Comment: @nynohu Do you mean in the `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: Of course viewDidLoad is running on main thread. But each time you have any changing UI, you should run it on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try setting an empty attributed string:

```
let emptyAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
textView.attributedText = emptyAttributedString
```

Perhaps you could place this within the IB Action hooked to your `clear` button?

Comment: Thanks for the help, Andy! I tried setting this as an empty attributed string, but it didn't help.